# Sharepoint 2010: Approve Blogpost with REST

Tags: 2010, blog, rest

Is there a way to automatically approve Blogposts I created with a .Net Webrequest/REST?
I can currently add posts to the Blogs list just fine, but I can't get them to be approved/be published automatically...

Comment: I too am trying to do something like this. I get an error that the column _ModerationStatus is not valid on the item type. Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @El Hombre `postItem["_ModerationStatus"] = "0";` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you should be able to do this. The field you want to explore is _moderationstatus. [Here](http://sharepointwriting.blogspot.com/2011/10/internal-value-for-approval-status.html) someone has listed all the status values.